# Angular Reactive Form : Values not updating the component code and also inserting existing record as new record before saving to the database

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am building an angular 7 application with reactive form and having dynamic controls implemented. I am having two issues while updating the record.

1. Whatever change I make in the input fields is not reflected while saving the record. So while debugging my form object does not contain the modified values.So for e.g the Name and ShortName field.
2. I have address field that I am dynamically adding. Say I have two addresses fields that are displayed on the screen. If I click the save button the two records are added as additional two records and not updating the existing record.

Component code

```
import { Component, Injectable, NgZone, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirmService } from '../services/firm.service';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { CommonDataService } from '../services/common.data.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { ListItem } from '../models/listItem';



@Component({
    selector: 'mgr-firm',
    templateUrl: './firm.component.html'
})
export class FirmComponent implements OnInit {
    private Error: string;
    public FirmDetails: any;
    public EditMode: boolean;
    public Editor = ClassicEditor;
    public EditorConfig: string;
    public originalContactList: any;
    public originalCityList: any;
    public events: string[] = [];
    @Input() FirmId: number;
    DateFoundedDate: Date;
    public frmFirm: FormGroup;
    public value: Date = new Date();


    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private firmService: FirmService, private commonDataService: CommonDataService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initializeFormModel();
        this.getFirmDetails();
    }


    initializeFormModel() {
        this.frmFirm = this._fb.group({
            firmName: [''],
            shortName: [''],
            alternateName: [''],
            dateFounded: [''],
            // intraLinks: this._fb.array([
            //     this.createCredentials()
            // ]),
            firmHistory: [''],
            People: [''],
            websites: this._fb.array([
                this.createWebsite()
            ]),
            addressess: this._fb.array([
                this.createAddress()
            ])
        });
    }


    public addWebsite(): void {
        this.websites.push(this.createWebsite());
    }

    public removeWebsite(index: number): void {
        const websites = this.frmFirm.get('websites') as FormArray;
        websites.removeAt(index);
    }

    private createWebsite(): FormGroup {
        return this._fb.group({
            websiteUrl: [''],
            username: [''],
            password: ['']
        });
    }



    public addAddress(): void {
        this.addressess.push(this.createAddress());
    }

    public removeAddress(index: number): void {
        const addressess = this.frmFirm.get('addressess') as FormArray;
        addressess.removeAt(index);
    }

    private createAddress(): FormGroup {
        return this._fb.group({
            // city: [''],
            street: [''],
            line2: [''],
            line3: [''],
            // zipCode: [''],
            phone: ['']
        });
    }




    get websites(): FormArray {
        return <FormArray>this.frmFirm.get('websites');
    }

    get addressess(): FormArray {
        return <FormArray>this.frmFirm.get('addressess');
    }



    get cities(): ListItem[] {
        return JSON.parse(this.FirmDetails.LongCitiesJson).map(x => new ListItem(x.CITY_ID, x.CITY_NAME, null));
    }


    setFormValues(FirmDetails: any) {
        this.frmFirm.patchValue({
            firmName: FirmDetails.Firm.NAME,
            shortName: FirmDetails.Firm.SHORT_NAME,
            alternateName: FirmDetails.Firm.ALTERNATE_NAME,
            dateFounded: this.getDate(FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED),
            firmHistory: FirmDetails.Firm.HISTORY_HTML,
            People: FirmDetails.People

        });


        const addressGroup = FirmDetails.Firm.Addresses.map(address => {
            return this._fb.group({
                street: [address.LINE1],
                line2:  [address.LINE2],
                line3:  [address.LINE3],
                phone:  [address.SWITCHBOARD_INT]
            });
        });
        const addressFormArray: FormArray = this._fb.array(addressGroup);
        this.frmFirm.setControl('addressess', addressFormArray);


        const websiteGroup = FirmDetails.Firm.Websites.map(website => {
           return this._fb.group({
                websiteUrl: [website.WEBSITE_URL],
                username:   [website.USERNAME],
                password:   [website.PASSWORD]
            });
        });
        const wesbiteFormArray: FormArray = this._fb.array(websiteGroup);
        this.frmFirm.setControl('websites', wesbiteFormArray);
    }

    getFirmDetails() {
        if (this.FirmId != null) {
            this.firmService.getFirmDetails(this.FirmId)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.FirmDetails = data;
                    this.originalContactList = this.FirmDetails.People;
                    this.originalCityList = JSON.parse(this.FirmDetails.LongCitiesJson);
                    this.setFormValues(this.FirmDetails);
                },
                    err => {
                        this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
                    },
                    () => {
                    });
        }
    }

    get dateFoundedDate(): string {
        if (this.FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED != null) {
        const dateString = this.FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED;
        const results = parseInt(dateString.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)[^+]\//i, "$1"));
        const date = new Date(results);
        const month = date.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long' });
        return (month + '-' + date.getFullYear());
        }
    }

    private getDate(dateFounded: string): Date {
        if (dateFounded != null) {
        const results = parseInt(dateFounded.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)[^+]\//i, "$1"));
        const date = new Date(results);
        return new Date(date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate());
        }
    }

    saveManager() {
        this.firmService.createFirm(this.FirmDetails)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.getFirmDetails();
                this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
            },
                err => {
                    this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
                },
                () => {
                });
    }

    public keyContactChange(value: any): void {
        this.FirmDetails.Firm.KEY_CONTACT_ID = value;
    }

    public dateFoundedChanged(value: Date): void {
        this.FirmDetails.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED = value;
    }


    handleFilter(value) {
        if (value.length >= 1) {
            this.FirmDetails.People = this.originalContactList.filter((s) => s.FIRST_NAME.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
        } else {
            this.FirmDetails.People = this.originalContactList;
        }
    }

}
```

UI

```
<style>
    .desc-header {
        background-color: #FAE7D6;
        color: black
    }

    .header {
        width: 8%;
    }


    .panel-heading {
        color: white;
        background-color: #F59850;
        border-color: #ddd;
    }

    .scrollClass {
        height: 800px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;


    }
</style>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        <span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Firm Details</span>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px;">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }"><input
                    type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="EditMode" class="hidden">Edit Mode</label>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

        <form [formGroup]="frmFirm" (ngSubmit)="saveManager()">
            <div *ngIf="FirmDetails && FirmDetails.Firm" class="card-body scrollClass" style="width:100%">

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 col-form-label modal-label header">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FirmDetails.Firm.NAME}}</div>
                        <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                            formControlName="firmName" />
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Short Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FirmDetails.Firm.SHORT_NAME}}</div>
                        <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                            formControlName="shortName" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Alternate Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FirmDetails.Firm.ALTERNATE_NAME}}</div>
                        <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                            formControlName="alternateName" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Date Founded</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{dateFoundedDate}}</div>
                        <kendo-datepicker *ngIf="EditMode" [format]="'MMMM yyyy'" (valueChange)="dateFoundedChanged($event)"  formControlName="dateFounded">
                        </kendo-datepicker>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Key Contact</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode && FirmDetails.People">{{FirmDetails.KeyContact.Name}}</div>
                        <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [data]="FirmDetails.People"
                            formControlName="People" [defaultItem]="FirmDetails.KeyContact.Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" (valueChange)="keyContactChange($event)"
                            [filterable]="true" (filterChange)="handleFilter($event)" textField="Name" valueField="ID">
                        </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Websites</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label for="inputEmail">Website URL</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label for="inputEmail">User Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label for="inputEmail">Password</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div formArrayName="websites"
                            *ngFor="let item of frmFirm.get('websites').controls; let i = index; let last = last">
                            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input style="width:100%" formControlName="websiteUrl"
                                            placeholder="Website Url">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input style="width:100%" formControlName="username" placeholder="User Name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input style="width:100%" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div *ngIf="EditMode" class="col-md-3">
                                        <button (click)="removeWebsite()">Remove Website</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="EditMode">
                            <button (click)="addWebsite()">Add Website</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">


                        <div formArrayName="addressess"
                            *ngFor="let item of frmFirm.get('addressess').controls; let i = index;">

                            <div [formGroupName]="i">

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-1 col-form-label header" attr.for="{{'streetId' + i}}">Street
                                        1</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="{{'streetId' + i}}" type="text"
                                            placeholder="Street address (required)" formControlName="street">

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-1 col-form-label header" attr.for="{{'line2Id' + i}}">Line
                                        2</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="{{'line2Id' + i}}" type="text"
                                            placeholder="Street address (second line)" formControlName="line2">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-1 col-form-label header" attr.for="{{'line3Id' + i}}">Line
                                        3</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="{{'line3Id' + i}}" type="text"
                                            placeholder="Street address (third line)" formControlName="line3">
                                    </div>
                                </div>



                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-1 col-form-label header" attr.for="{{'phoneId' + i}}">Phone
                                        </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="{{'phoneId' + i}}" type="text"
                                            placeholder="Phone" formControlName="phone">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="EditMode">
                            <button (click)="addAddress()">Add Address</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:10px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 30px;">
                        <div class="desc-header">Firm History</div>
                        <div class="divEditor">
                            <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [id]="'ckFirmHistory'" *ngIf="EditMode"
                                formControlName="firmHistory" style="font-size: 11px;" debounce="500"
                                [config]="EditorConfig">
                            </ckeditor>
                            <div style="padding: 10px" *ngIf="!EditMode" [innerHTML]="FirmDetails.Firm.HISTORY_HTML">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>
            <div class="btn-toolbar" style="padding-top:40px;">
                <span> <button class="btn btn-default btn mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
                        Download Template
                    </button>
                </span>
                <span> <button class="btn btn-default btn mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
                        Upload Template Data
                    </button>
                </span>
                <span *ngIf="EditMode"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3">Save</button>

                </span>
                <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                        (click)="cancelManager">Cancel</button>
                </span>
                <span><button type="button" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all"
                        (click)="deleteManager()">Delete</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

serverside controller code

```
[HttpPut]
        [SkipTokenAuthorization]
        public void CreateFirm(FirmViewModel model)
        {

            var firmService = GetService<FIRM>();

            var firm = firmService.GetWithIncludes(model.Firm.ID);

            if (firm != null)
            {
                firm.NAME = model.Firm.NAME;
                firm.SHORT_NAME = model.Firm.SHORT_NAME;
                firm.KEY_CONTACT_ID = model.Firm.KEY_CONTACT_ID;
                firm.ALTERNATE_NAME = model.Firm.ALTERNATE_NAME;
                firm.DATE_FOUNDED = model.Firm.DATE_FOUNDED;
                firm.HISTORY_HTML = model.Firm.HISTORY_HTML;
                firm.Addresses = model.Firm.Addresses;
                firm.Websites=  model.Websites;
                firmService.Update(firm);
            }
            else
            {
                //var m = new MANAGER(){PERSON = new PERSON()};
                //m.PERSON.EMAIL_ADDRESS1 = model.Person.EMAIL_ADDRESS1;

            }
```

Comment: All changed values should be in `this.frmFirm.value` but you never use it in your code. Try to use it

Answer (score 0):

1) your `saveManager` does not seem to be reading the values from `frmFirm` and instead is submitting your data object `FirmDetails` -- you'll need to update your model (or better yet a copy of your model) with the form values before submitting it to the server.

2) is your server-side 'firmService.Update' respecting existing addresses in the model?  are you passing ids appropriately to ensure existing addresses are not re-added?  this seems the likely cause of your duplicates